# Torch allocates zero GPU memory on PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to use GPU to train my model but it seems that torch fails to allocate GPU memory.

My model is a RNN built on PyTorch

```py
device = torch.device('cuda: 0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

rnn = RNN(n_letters, n_hidden, n_categories_train)
rnn.to(device)
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
criterion.to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(rnn.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=.9)
```

```py
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.output_size = output_size

        self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)

        self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        input = input.cuda()
        hidden = hidden.cuda()

        combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
        hidden = self.i2h(combined)
        output = self.i2o(combined)
        output = self.softmax(output)

        output = output.cuda()
        hidden = hidden.cuda()

        return output, hidden

    def init_hidden(self):
        return Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size).cuda())
```

Training function:

```py
def train(category_tensor, line_tensor, rnn, optimizer, criterion):
    rnn.zero_grad()
    hidden = rnn.init_hidden()

    for i in range(line_tensor.size()[0]):
        output, hidden = rnn(line_tensor[i], hidden)

    loss = criterion(output, category_tensor)
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()

    return output, loss.item()
```

The function to get category_tensor and line_tensor:

```py
def random_training_pair(category_lines, n_letters, all_letters):
    category = random.choice(all_categories_train)
    line = random.choice(category_lines[category])
    category_tensor = Variable(torch.LongTensor([all_categories_train.index(category)]).cuda())
    line_tensor = Variable(process_data.line_to_tensor(line, n_letters, all_letters)).cuda()

    return category, line, category_tensor, line_tensor
```

I ran the following the code:

```
 print(torch.cuda.get_device_name(0))
 print('Memory Usage:')
 print('Allocated:', round(torch.cuda.memory_allocated(0) / 1024 ** 3, 1), 'GB')
 print('Cached:   ', round(torch.cuda.memory_cached(0) / 1024 ** 3, 1), 'GB')
```

and I got:

```
GeForce GTX 1060
Memory Usage:
Allocated: 0.0 GB
Cached:    0.0 GB
```

I did not get any errors but GPU usage is just 1% while CPU usage is around 31%.

I am using Windows 10 and Anaconda, where my PyTorch is installed. CUDA and cuDNN is installed from .exe file downloaded from Nvidia website.

Comment: I don't see where in the code above you do anything else than print how much memory is allocated. It would seem obvious that there won't be a need to allocate memory for not doing anything!?

Comment: I printed this out during the training process and no memory is allocated still

Comment: Is your model on GPU? Can you show model/training code?

Comment: I have included my model in the post. It should be on GPU.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `to()` is not an in-place operation. If you call `rnn.to(device)` it will *return* a *new object / model* located on the desired *device*. But it will not move the old object anywhere!

So changing:

```
rnn = RNN(n_letters, n_hidden, n_categories_train)
rnn.to(device)
```

to:

```
rnn = RNN(n_letters, n_hidden, n_categories_train).to(device)
```

For all other instances you used `to` this way, you have to change it as well.

Should do the trick for you!

*Note: All tensors and parameters you perform operations with have to be on the same device. If your model is on GPU but your input tensor is on CPU you will get an error message.*

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but nothing's changed, the model is still training on GPU.

Comment: @IDoNot1xist Didn't you actually want to train on GPU? So whatever device you want to train on, I suggest, you try to do some simple operations first on your device. So checking if `x = torch.rand(1000, 1000, 1000).to(device)` works for you. If `device` is the correct device you want to use, it should either work or raise in error.

Comment: Why to say that `to()` is not an in-place operation? As [document](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.to) mentioned, "This method modifies the module in-place". Therefore, `to()` is an in-place operation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by that the CUDA version of PyTorch is not installed correctly. If the CUDA version is installed, then the following statement

```py
device = torch.device('cuda: 0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

will raise `RuntimeError`:

```
RuntimeError: Invalid device string: 'cuda: 0'
```

Because the correct usage is `cuda:0` without a space.

You should check the version first. For example, type `conda list` as follows:

```bash
$ conda list

# packages in environment at /home/maniac/.conda/envs/torch:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
...
torch                     2.0.0+cu118              pypi_0    pypi
...
```

`+cu118` shows that the CUDA version of PyTorch is correctly installed. If the version shows `2.0.0+cpu`, then PyTorch runs with CPU.